# Mutating properties in methods

Tags: c#, mono

I have these properties:

```
private float colorR;
private float colorG;
private float colorB;

public static float defaultInc = 0.001f;

private float addR = defaultInc;
private float addG = defaultInc;
private float addB = defaultInc;
```

In my Update method I'm doing the following:

```
void Update()
{

    if (colorR + addR > 1.0f) {
        addR = addR * -1;
    } else if (colorR + addR < 0.0f) {
        addR = defaultInc;
    }
    colorR += addR;

    if (colorG + addG > 1.0f) {
        addG = addG * -1;
    } else if (colorG + addG < 0.0f) {
        addG = defaultInc;
    }
    colorG += addG;

    if (colorB + addB > 1.0f) {
        addB = addB * -1;
    } else if (colorB + addB < 0.0f) {
        addB = defaultInc;
    }
    colorB += addB;

    setColor();
    
}
```

As you can see I'm performing the same calculation 3 times for 6 different properties. My question is, how can I refactor this so that it uses one or 2 methods to update the properties, rather than repeating myself. I tried passing the properties into a method and mutating them there, but the method scope prevents it.

Comment: Pedantic, perhaps, but those aren't properties, they're fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass by reference using [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref):

```
void Update(ref float color, ref float add)
{
    if (color + add > 1.0f)
    {
        add = add * -1;
    }
    else if (color + add < 0.0f)
    {
        add = defaultInc;
    }
    color += add;
}

void Update()
{
    Update(ref colorR, ref addR);
    Update(ref colorG, ref addG);
    Update(ref colorB, ref addB);
}
```

Because each field is passed by reference, the method can update them directly.

Comment: Thanks! I notice the method names are the same... presumably since the signatures are different then there is no collision?

Comment: That's right; they're overloaded. So calling `Update()` without arguments invokes the method with no arguments in it's signature.